# Get the cause of a react rendering call

Tags: reactjs, debugging

I have a component, that under certain conditions, will keep getting rendered in a seemingly infinite loop. There's a lot of code, and it'd take quite a bit of time to put it in a clean stackoverflow question, but is there a way, either in the code or in the debugger, to see what the source of the rerender was? I.e. where props or state was changed higher up in the render tree to cause the rerender?

Comment: Can you show us the component code? just the component, as a gist maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a lot of `console.log`ing in your future.  Start at the last component and output the `props` and `state` to see what's changing and where it's coming from, then move up a level and repeat until you find the culprit.

There is [this tool](https://github.com/garbles/why-did-you-update) which might be able to help you narrow the field of suspects.

Good luck.  Hopefully someone else knows a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I would propose to play around with https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/perf.html.

With print wasted method you can get very useful information about which component was rerendered unnecessarily and which component invoked that action.

More over, print operations gives you acess to information about what operation invoked rerender.

I have created simple component that makes the use of these perf functions easier:

*js:*

```
import React, { PureComponent, PropTypes } from 'react'
import Perf from 'react-addons-perf'

class PerfProfiler extends PureComponent {

state = {
  isStarted: false,
  isMinimized: this.props.minimized,
}

toggle = () => {
  const { isStarted } = this.state

this.setState({
  isStarted: !isStarted,
}, () => {
   if (isStarted) { Perf.stop() }
   else { Perf.start() }
  })
}

toggleContent = () => {
  const { isMinimized } = this.state
  this.setState({
    isMinimized: !isMinimized,
  })
}

printWasted = () => {
  const lastMeasurement = Perf.getLastMeasurements()
  return Perf.printWasted(lastMeasurement)
}

printOperations = () => {
  const lastMeasurement = Perf.getLastMeasurements()
  return Perf.printOperations(lastMeasurement)
}

printExclusive = () => {
  const lastMeasurement = Perf.getLastMeasurements()
  return Perf.printExclusive(lastMeasurement)
}

printInclusive = () => {
  const lastMeasurement = Perf.getLastMeasurements()
  return Perf.printInclusive(lastMeasurement)
}

render() {
  const { position, className } = this.props
  const { isMinimized } = this.state
  return (
    <div className={`perf-profiler ${position} ${className}`}>
      <div className="min-button-container">
        <button onClick={this.toggleContent}>_</button>
      </div>
      <div className={`buttons-container ${isMinimized ? 'hidden' : 
''}`}>
      <button className="toggle-button" onClick={this.toggle}>
        {this.state.isStarted ? 'Stop' : 'Start'}
      </button>
      <button onClick={this.printWasted}>Print Wasted</button>
      <button onClick={this.printOperations}>Print Operations</button>
      <button onClick={this.printInclusive}>Print Inclusive</button>
      <button onClick={this.printExclusive}>Print Exclusive</button>
    </div>
  </div>)}
}
export default PerfProfiler
```

*css:*

```
.perf-profiler {

display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
position: absolute;
border: 1px solid;
padding: 20px;
background-color: rgba(#ffffff, 0.8);
z-index: 10;

&.top-left {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

&.top-right {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

&.bottom-left {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

&.bottom-right {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}

&.center {
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}

.toggle-button {
  margin-left: 0.5em;
}

.min-button-container {
  display: flex;

  flex: 1;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.buttons-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
}
```

What you do, is simply import this component into your parent component, click on start, play around with app, press stop and print wasted/print operations. Information about wasted rerenders/invoked operations will be shown in the console.

*Example use case:*

[image: Example use of the component]

Remember to *npm i react-addons-perf --save-dev* , befor using this component